# safe static destructors when multiple threads call exit()

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, exit

How do I safely delete static C++ objects in the case when multiple (Posix) threads call `exit()` in parallel?

It appears in my CentOS6 environment that `exit()` executes `atexit` (or `on_exit`) cleanup handlers by calling something like `fct[--cnt]()` where `cnt` is the number of handlers registered. When multiple threads call `exit()` at the same time, we have a race condition in the unprotected `--cnt` operation and some handlers may be skipped or called multiple times (leading to the occasional crash).
So how can I ensure that just one of the `exit()` calling threads does the cleanup and all others stop? Note that inserting a `pthread_mutex_lock()` into a cleanup handler doesn't help because this handler might be skipped...

Unfortunately I can't avoid that multiple threads call `exit()` because that's code my users will write (I'm providing a library to them).

Looking for safe ideas, thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you worried about? Do you have something in your statically allocated objects that MUST be clenaed up (if so what)? It is generally safe to exit without cleanup in modern sophisticated OS's. If you HAVE to do cleanup, then I would suggest that you probably need to find a better solution than let your client code call exit - such as implement your code in a shared library, and use the shared library cleanup function to clean up, perhaps? Or document that "you must not call `exit()`, use `my_safe_exit()`", and then refer to that when customers complain that it doesn't work.

Comment: In addition to the above, what if your clients are crashing out (stack fault, seg fault) or debugging and exiting in the debugger without calling exit at all?

Comment: I have some static objects that C++ will destroy, but cannot do safely in parallel (race condition in destructors). This cleanup is needed, for example, to properly close tracing file streams, so automatic cleanup by the OS is not an option.

Comment: So let the cleanup do safe things like `stream::flush()`, but don't actively close it in the destructor?

Comment: Asking for calling my_safe_exit() instead is not good either, because a lot of existing code (at my users' side) would need to be changed.

Comment: If the clients "are crashing out" or aborting, then all of this is not needed. Buf if they create two parallel instances that call exit() at some point, this should be safe and cleanly exit the program.

Comment: Re "safe things like stream::flush()": this is exactly not safely doable because this handler might be skipped due to that race condition! One thread might work on this while some other thread already quits to the OS which then kills the cleaning thread in the middle of its action...  :-(

Comment: This seems like a something you can't fix to me - other than `#define exit() my_safe_exit()` in some suitable place(s).

Comment: That was my conclusion as well, but I thought some clever geniuses like you could come up with a good idea. Thanks a lot for your quick answers!

Comment: Of course there is the ostrich solution too: If you stick your head in the sand and ignore the problem, it MAY go away. How likely is it actually that multiple threads call `exit` at the same time? [This may be a design issue in the application, that for some reason they send a message to every thread, which does some sort of synchronised mass-exit - but really, is that a good idea?]

Comment: pthread_once might be helpful here

Comment: The C/C++ standard states that behavior is undefined if a program calls exit more than once.  If the user is writing such code, it's their problem, and you can point them to the standard.  However, if you are creating the threads within your library that my call exit, you'll need to properly clean up all your threads before exiting.

Answer (score 1):

There is no portable way to handle multiple calls to exit() - because it is undefined (behaviour) what happens in that case.

But, for some particular platform you may find a way to do it. A somewhat generic solution to the "called multiple times" is to have a flag in your static objects like "am I already destructed". As usual, you may hide that in a template:

```
template <typename T> class StaticExitHandled {
public:
    std::unique_ptr<T> t_;
    ~StaticExitHandled() { t_.release(); }
};
```

Now just remember to declare all your static objects with this template. That is just the core of it, add bells and whistles as per your taste. Also, instead of std::unique_ptr<> you may use boost::optional<> or some such thing.

I don't think there is a generic solution to "not called at all".

Actually, I would advise against having non-trivial static objects in multi-threaded environment. So, only have static PODs and objects with severely constrained destructors (depending on what is safe to do at this point in your environment - i.e. closing file handles is OK in most environments).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using gcc, you can use the code below to define a cleanup procedure:

```
void __attribute__ ((destructor)) my_fini(void);
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, how about defining a single object with static duration whose destructor would take care of your cleanup?